# Combination of errors question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

A resistance **R** is in series with an inductance **L**. At angular frequency **ω** the
magnitude of the complex impedance **Z** of this combination is given by
**|Z|**^2 = **R**^2 + (**ωL**)^2
.
Find |**Z**|, and the error in |**Z**|, given that **R**= (100Ω) ± 1% and **ωL** = 135 ± 6Ω.

My attempt:

**|Z|**^2 = (10,000 ± 100)Ω + (18225 ± 36)Ω

**|Z|**^2 = (28225± x)Ω

I put in "x" as the error in |Z|, because I'm not sure what the best way of combining these errors is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the general case corresponding to your question would be finding the uncertainty on: $$A=B*B+C*C$$

For a simple sum we have: $$A=B+C \rightarrow \delta A=\sqrt{(\delta B)^2+(\delta C)^2}$$

And for $$A=B^n \rightarrow \delta A=A|n|\frac{\delta B}{B}$$

Combining the two, for $A=B^2+C^2$ we have then:

$$\delta A=A\sqrt{\left(2\frac{\delta B}{B}\right)^2+\left(2\frac{\delta C}{C}\right)^2}$$

or more simply your $x$ would be $$\delta A=2A\sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta B}{B}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\delta C}{C}\right)^2}$$

Now substitute $A$ with $Z^2$, $B$ with $R$ and $C$ with $\omega L$ and you'll have your formula.

Finally, in case you have the errors of $\omega$ and $L$ separately, then for $\omega L$ you'd have: $$\delta (\omega L)=\omega L \sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta \omega}{\omega}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\delta L}{L}\right)^2}$$

I leave the numerical calculations to yourself.